# Detecting new files in a folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an application which has 10,000+ files in a directory.  Once a day a few more files are added to the directory.  In theory these files don't change.  The problem is that it takes lots of time to check to make sure these files aren't in the database.  I looked at FileSystemWatcher class but my app doesn't always run 24/7.  It is also possible that the file timestamp may be older than the newest file.  Therefore I can not count on file timestamps.

Having a false positive on a new file is better than a false negative.

I am looking for suggestions on a way to speed this up.

This is a Window 7+ and .NET app.

Comment: For suggestions to speed things up, you'll need to post a snippet of the code you have now.

Comment: I have a similar thing (although with a lot fewer files). We have the app scan the directory on startup and then use a FileSystemWatcher while it's running.  It's an ugly solution (especially if there are already 10,000 files in the directory), but after processing a file we create another file named something like "original_filename.done".

Comment: If you can, separate your files into subfolders (maybe per month, something like 201409, 201410, 201411, etc.) to keep the number of files lower in a single folder. 10,000 files in a folder slows down the file system functions considerably for that folder.

Comment: Just how do you determine the file is in the database?

Comment: `The problem is that it takes lots of time to check to make sure these files aren't in the database` Where is the code that does this?

Comment: You guys are great.  You pointed me in a direction that I didn't think about.  I had an observable collection for my list of files, which I was doing a linq query on to check to see if it was in the database.  I added a sorted list to mirror the observable collection and used it to check for existing in the database.  It still takes a bit of time to read the directory, but it much faster.  thanks

Comment: So you are comparing the whole file?  Take a hash and compare the hash.

Comment: No, just the file name is being compared.    I do hash and keep the hash.  If a new file is added then I check to see if the hash exist.  Currently the db is a json file.  I had it as a SQL-CE database with EF, but that was away too slow.  However I am now thinking that if I make a sorted list of the db I can return to that.  Not the top of my list right now.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you are just comparing names and hashes that should only be seconds.  Intersection of two HashSet of 100,000 string each is less than 1 second.

Comment: Except I don't have the file hash.  I would have to compute it and compare it against what is in the database.  That would take some time.